# What material to use for curved step?

Tags: stairs, trim

I am adding a step to a step-down living room to cut a 9" rise into two 4.5" steps. I was looking at Flex Trim for the riser, but the description says 10" minimum bend radius. I aim to have a 6" radius curve.

Comment: What are the measurements for the whole thing? Depth of curve, width of step, etc

Comment: Also, is concrete an option or are you looking for a wood/wood-like only solution?

Comment: 8' wide and 14-16" deep. It will be wood. White riser and oak step stained same color as the LR floor.

Comment: What part will have a 6" radius? Providing a sketch, even if not to scale, with the dimensions drawn on will help people come up with ideas for you.

Comment: Here's an example: https://www.stepupstair.com/products/8060-48-double-bull-nose-quarter-circle

That one has a radius of 7" according to diagram. My step will be 78" wide and 14" deep and 4.5" tall. 

I know someone with a bunch of old oak from a barn. Another idea is to have two oak boards as base and a top board that overhangs. His boards are 2" and could be planed to 1.5". Three would give me my 4.5"

Comment: You will find your answer here,  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/231705/how-can-i-bend-plywood-around-a-stair-riser     The accepted answer here is what I was going to suggest, I was looking online for a picture to show what it looks like, and found one as a post here on SE.

Comment: The appropriate action, @Jack, would be VtC as a duplicate...